# Call Xib Class from Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, xib

I have a storyboard based project

I need to call a UIViewController class which is Xib based.

how can i call Xib class from storyboard and vice-versa?

Comment: Check my answer iphonemaclover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 3 controllers.ViewController and ThirdViewController in Storybboard.SecondViewController is XIB part.

**First I call XIB from Storyboard**

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController 


- (IBAction)actionGoXIB:(id)sender
{
  SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
}
```

**Now I call Stoyboard from XIB**

If you want to acheive this, first Go to Storyboard Click ThirdViewController

> Click->Identity Inspector
>
> Then Click -> Identity
>
> Now Set the Storyboard ID to ThirdViewController in the Identity
>   section

See the screenshots below

[image]
[image]

SeconViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "ThirdViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (IBAction)actionGoStoryboard:(id)sender
{
  UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
  ThirdViewController *thirdVC = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ThirdViewController"];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdVC animated:YES];
  // [self presentViewController:thirdVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: what about if need to use presentViewController ? not navigationController?

Comment: you can use present view controller not  a problem.But don't mingle with push and present to view controller.If you use both ,set and let give the way for separate view controller.If you want to navigate using push use that for one view controller and also if you want to present the view controller,use another view controller from same view controller.